# Проблема с установкой Lubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Пробую установить **Lubuntu 18** с флешки, разделил диск на два, один **ext4** на 40 гб поставил **/**, а второй 80 гб поставил **/home**, после нажатия на установку вылетает ошибка. 
Уже многое пробовал и форматировать и тд, но толку 0. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по сообщению - не удалось примонтировать cdrom/usb флешку. К форматированию диска это не имеет отношения. Может попробовать перезаписать образ?

Comment: Спасибо. Нету возможности, флешка одна с системой. А загрузиться в систему уже не могу.

Comment: Писал через `dd`?